# Are these two ways of constructing an object in JavaScript equivalent?

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
    function A(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

is:

```
    var a1 = new A("A1");
```

exactly equivalent to:

```
    var a1 = {};
    A.call(a1, "A1");
    a1.__proto__ = A.prototype;
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's the issue that `__proto__` is non-standard ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) and not supported by all implementations. :-) Other than that, the `constructor` property ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)) wouldn't be set correctly, you'd probably have to do that yourself. Also, I think you'd be best off setting the prototype *before* calling the constructor function. So:

```
function A(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var a1 = {};
a1.__proto__ = A.prototype;
a1.constructor = A; // <=== Added this bit
A.call(a1, "A1");   // <=== Moved this down
```

It's close, though, at least on implementations that support `__proto__`. I wouldn't bet on it being exactly the same. Worth having a read of the ECMAScript 5th edition spec for more details, particular Sections 11.2.2 "*The `new` operator*" and 13.2.2 "*[[Construct]]*".

Some implementations that don't support `__proto__` may support the new `Object.create` function defined by the 5th edition spec (Section 15.2.3.5), which allows you to create an object with a specific prototype. In implementations that support `Object.create`, the code creating `a1` would look like this:

```
var a1 = Object.create(A.prototype);
a1.constructor = A;
A.call(a1, "A1");
```

Rolling it up, then:

```
function A(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

if (typeof Object.create === "function") {
    a1 = Object.create(A.prototype);
}
else if ({}.__proto__) {
    a1 = {};
    a1.__proto__ = A.prototype;
}
else {
    /* Fail */
}
a1.constructor = A;
A.call(a1, "A1");
```

...but that's completely untested and, again, I wouldn't count on it being *exactly* the same barring a very close read of the spec indeed.

Whenever possible, of course, if you're dealing with a constructor function, I'd recommend using it in the normal way. Advanced tools like `__proto__` and `Object.create` are useful for doing pure prototypical inheritance (no constructor function required), though.