# dynamic object construction in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-languages

When I want to call a function in javascript with arguments supplied from elsewhere I can use the `apply` method of the function like:

```
array = ["arg1", 5, "arg3"] 
...
someFunc.apply(null, array);
```

but what if I need to call a constructor in a similar fashion? This does not seem to work:

```
array = ["arg1", 5, "arg3"] 
...
someConstructor.apply({}, array);
```

at least not as I am attempting:

```
template = ['string1', string2, 'etc'];
var resultTpl = Ext.XTemplate.apply({}, template);
```

this does not work wither:

```
Ext.XTemplate.prototype.constructor.apply({}, template);
```

Any way to make that one work? (In this particular case I found that `new Ext.XTemplate(template)` will work, but I am interested in the general case)

similar question but specific to built-in types and without an answer I can use:
[Instantiating a JavaScript object by calling prototype.constructor.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181348/instantiating-a-javascript-object-by-calling-prototypeconstructorapply)

Thank you.

## Edit:

Time has passed and ES6 and transpilers are now a thing.
In ES6 it is trivial to do what I wanted: `new someConstructor(...array)`.
[Babel](http://babeljs.io) will turn that into ES5 `new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(someConstructor, [null].concat(array)))();` which is explained in [How to construct JavaScript object (using 'apply')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226646/how-to-construct-javascript-object-using-apply/4226801#4226801).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no simple, straightforward way to do this with a constructor function. This is because special things happen when you use the `new` keyword to call a constructor function, and so if you're not going to do that, you have to emulate all of those special things. They are:

1. Creating a new object instance (you're doing that).
2. Setting that object's internal prototype to constructor function's `prototype` property.
3. Setting that object's `constructor` property.
4. Calling the constructor function with that object instance as the `this` value (you're doing that).
5. Handling the special return value from the constructor function.

I *think* that's about it, but worth double-checking in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

So if you can avoid it and just use the constructor function directly, I'd do that. :-) If you can't, though, you can still do it, it's just awkward and involves workarounds. (See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853978/are-these-two-ways-of-constructing-an-object-in-javascript-equivalent/3853998#3853998) here on StackOverflow, although I cover all of the ground here [and then some] as well.)

Your biggest issue is #2 above: Setting the internal prototype of the object. For a long time, there was no standard way to do this. Some browsers supported a `__proto__` property that did it, so you can use that if it's there. The good news is that ECMAScript 5 introduces a way to do this explicitly: `Object.create`. So cutting-edge browsers like Chrome will have that. But if you're dealing with a browser that has neither `Object.create` nor `__proto__`, it gets a bit ugly:

1) Define a custom constructor function.

2) Set its `prototype` property to the `prototype` property of the real constructor function

3) Use it to create a blank object instance.

That handles the prototype for you. Then you continue with:

4) Replace the `constructor` property on that instance with the real constructor function.

5) Call the real constructor function via `apply`.

6) If the return value of the real constructor function is an object, use it instead of the one you created; otherwise, use the one you created.

Something like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ibusi3/3)):

```
function applyConstruct(ctor, params) {
    var obj, newobj;

    // Use a fake constructor function with the target constructor's
    // `prototype` property to create the object with the right prototype
    function fakeCtor() {
    }
    fakeCtor.prototype = ctor.prototype;
    obj = new fakeCtor();

    // Set the object's `constructor`
    obj.constructor = ctor;

    // Call the constructor function
    newobj = ctor.apply(obj, params);

    // Use the returned object if there is one.
    // Note that we handle the funky edge case of the `Function` constructor,
    // thanks to Mike's comment below. Double-checked the spec, that should be
    // the lot.
    if (newobj !== null
        && (typeof newobj === "object" || typeof newobj === "function")
       ) {
        obj = newobj;
    }

    // Done
    return obj;
}
```

You could take it a step further and only use the fake constructor if necessary, looking to see if `Object.create` or `__proto__` are supported first, like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ibusi3/4)):

```
function applyConstruct(ctor, params) {
    var obj, newobj;

    // Create the object with the desired prototype
    if (typeof Object.create === "function") {
        // ECMAScript 5 
        obj = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
    }
    else if ({}.__proto__) {
        // Non-standard __proto__, supported by some browsers
        obj = {};
        obj.__proto__ = ctor.prototype;
        if (obj.__proto__ !== ctor.prototype) {
            // Setting it didn't work
            obj = makeObjectWithFakeCtor();
        }
    }
    else {
        // Fallback
        obj = makeObjectWithFakeCtor();
    }

    // Set the object's constructor
    obj.constructor = ctor;

    // Apply the constructor function
    newobj = ctor.apply(obj, params);

    // If a constructor function returns an object, that
    // becomes the return value of `new`, so we handle
    // that here.
    if (typeof newobj === "object") {
        obj = newobj;
    }

    // Done!
    return obj;

    // Subroutine for building objects with specific prototypes
    function makeObjectWithFakeCtor() {
        function fakeCtor() {
        }
        fakeCtor.prototype = ctor.prototype;
        return new fakeCtor();
    }
}
```

On Chrome 6, the above uses `Object.create`; on Firefox 3.6 and Opera, it uses `__proto__`. On IE8, it uses the fake constructor function.

The above is fairly off-the-cuff, but it mostly handles the issues I'm aware of in this area.

Comment: That sure was a bit more involved than I expected. Thank you though, for an excellent explanation!

Comment: @ormuriauga: :-)  Glad that helped. The explanation makes it seem a bit more complicated than it is (as explanations tend to do). As you can see from the first code snippet, it can actually be quite a brief bit of code.

Comment: even one-liners are often quite involved ;)
the finer details of the javascript Object model still evade me, but I bought "the good parts" now and will read it soon. Is there any good reason to use your latter code snippet when the shorter, and less complicated one, works? Would I gain any speed or compatibility or something else by using the newer features?

Comment: @ormuriauga: Funny, I was thinking about that too. I'm not sure you do, frankly, I'm not immediately seeing much benefit to detecting and using `Object.create` or `__proto__` when there's a universal and straightforward way to do it instead. I expect they're *slightly* faster, but you'd only need to worry about speed if you were doing it a **lot**. Re JavaScript's object model, the disarming thing about it is how incredibly simple it is. We have objects, and an object can be backed by a prototype object, which can in turn be backed by another prototype object, ad infinitum. (cont'd)

Comment: (continuing) There are no packages or classes (though we frequently call constructor functions classes). There are no methods, only functions (though when they're hooked to properties of objects we frequently *call* them methods). The language considers *almost everything* to be an object (including the context created when you call a function, which is how closures work). Etc. If you're interested, I've written up some disjointed thoughts on JavaScript over the years (including about classes, methods, `this` and how it differs from other languages, closures): http://blog.niftysnippets.org

Comment: I don't think this works for the `Function` constructor because the `typeof` check there returns `"function"`, and it fails for constructors that return `null` since `typeof null` is `"object"`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I made a version where the first call returns a function with a closure on the to-be-created object, which in turn takes normal function arguments rather than an array, using `arguments` with `apply`. Example: `var newMyObject = objectCreator(MyObject); var objinst = newMyObject(arg1, arg2, arg3);`. Of course, you can just chain them: `objectCreator(MyObject)(arg1, arg2, arg3)`. This pattern is now supremely useful for letting mixed VBScript/Javascript in an ASP Classic web page create new JS objects from VBScript without a special constructor function for each object type.

Comment: (continued) In VB you can then use exactly the same syntax, `objectCreator(MyObject)(arg1, arg2, arg3)` to simulate `new MyObject(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.

Comment: In ES5, `Function.prototype.bind` lets you separate the concerns of currying and constructing.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4226801/20394

Answer (score 5):

From [developer.mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):
Bound functions are automatically suitable for use with the new operator to construct new instances created by the target function. When a bound function is used to construct a value, the provided this is ignored. However, provided arguments are still prepended to the constructor call.

That said, we still need to use apply to get the arguments out of an array and into the bind call. Further, we need to also reset bind's function as the this argument of the apply function. This gives us a very succinct one-liner that does exactly as needed.

```
function constructorApply(ctor, args){
    return new (ctor.bind.apply(ctor, [null].concat(args)))();
};
```

Comment: Also from the relevant section in the linked source: "Warning: This section demonstrates JavaScript capabilities and documents some edge cases of the bind() method. The methods shown below are not the best way to do things and probably should not be used in any production environment."

Comment: If you wanted to make this args parameter agnostic between an actual array of arguments or an *Arguments* object, you could do something like ...... 

`// ...
function constructorApply(ctor, args){
  return new (ctor.bind.apply(ctor, [null].concat([].slice.call(args))))();
};`

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question is quite old, here's a simpler methods in practically any modern browser (as of writing, 2018, I'm counting Chrome, FF, IE11, Edge...).

```
var template = ['string1', string2, 'etc'];
var resultTpl = Object.create(Ext.XTemplate.prototype);
Ext.XTemplate.apply(resultTpl, template);
```

Those two lines also explain how the `new` operator basically works.

Comment: in a modern browser you can just do `new Ext.XTemplate(...template)`

Comment: Only if you are lucky and don't have to support the latest iteration of IE.

Comment: I guess it comes down to what you put in the word "modern" :)

Comment: That's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think another way of achieving this could be to extend the Ext Template class so that the constructor of the new object takes your array and does the stuff you want to do. This way all the constructing stuff would be done for you and you could just call the constructor of your superclass with your arguments.

Comment: In fact, it does -- in his question, he said *"(In this particular case I found that new Ext.XTemplate(template) will work, but I am interested in the general case)"*

Comment: I thought by general he meant something like I described. Sorry if I have misunderstood the question.