# How to construct JavaScript object (using 'apply')?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm looking for a way to construct arbitrary JavaScript objects based on (a) the name of the constructor, and (b) an array containing the arguments. I found this function (by Matthew Crumley ?) in an other thread on stackoverflow:

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
  function F() { return constructor.apply(this, args); }
  F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
  return new F();
}
```

This works well with constructors written in JavaScript, but it fails with a TypeError if I try construct(Date, [...]). I don't know yet if there are more native constructors that this function can't handle. My questions are then ...

- Are there functions in more recent versions of JavaScript (ECMAScript 5) that will solve my problem?
- If not, is there some way I can check the constructor in question to see if the above function can be used? (If it cannot, I may have to use eval("new "+cname+"("+arglist+")").)

/Jon

Comment: At least related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871731/dynamic-object-construction-in-javascript Either way, my answer there may help.

Comment: @TJC: great answer there (+1).  @user: TJ's answer in that question should help you get started.  Since you specifically mentioned `Date`, you might want to check out Kris Kowal's ECMA 5th shim which overrides the `Date` constructor by properly accounting for the variable number of arguments it can accept. https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js#L501

Answer (score 4):

In ES5, you can do it via [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
  return new (constructor.bind.apply(constructor, [null].concat(args)));
}
```

which works because `bind` still uses the [[Construct]] abstract operator when the bound function appears to the right of `new` per http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5.2 which says

> ## 15.3.4.5.2 [[Construct]]
>
> When the [[Construct]] internal method of a function object, F that was created using the `bind` function is called with a list of arguments ExtraArgs, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let target be the value of F’s [[TargetFunction]] internal property.
> 2. If target has no [[Construct]] internal method, a TypeError exception is thrown.
> 3. Let boundArgs be the value of F’s [[BoundArgs]] internal property.
> 4. Let args be a new list containing the same values as the list boundArgs in the same order followed by the same values as the list ExtraArgs in the same order.
> 5. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method of target providing args as the arguments.

but most implementations of `Function.prototype.bind` that attempt to back-port the language feature onto ES3 implementations do not correctly handle bound functions used as a constructor, so if you're not sure your code is running on a real ES5 implementation then you have to fall back to the triangle of hackery:

```
function applyCtor(ctor, args) {
  // Triangle of hackery which handles host object constructors and intrinsics.
  // Warning: The goggles! They do nothing!
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0: return new ctor;
    case 1: return new ctor(args[0]);
    case 2: return new ctor(args[0], args[1]);
    case 3: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    case 4: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    case 5: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
    case 6: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
    case 7: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6]);
    case 8: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7]);
    case 9: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8]);
    case 10: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9]);
    case 11: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10]);
    case 12: return new ctor(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10], args[11]);
  }
  // End triangle of hackery

  // Create a throwaway subclass of ctor whose constructor does nothing.
  function TemporarySubclass() {}
  TemporarySubclass.prototype = ctor.prototype;
  var instance = new TemporarySubclass();
  instance.constructor = ctor;  // Patch constructor property
  // Run the constructor.  This assumes that [[Call]] internal method is the same as
  // [[Construct]].  It might work with some builtins/host objects where "new` would not.
  var returnValue = ctor.apply(instance, args);
  // If the constructor returned a non-primitive value, return it instead.
  switch (typeof returnValue) {
    case 'object':
      // If ctor is Array, it reaches here so we don't use broken Array subclass.
      // Ditto for Date.
      if (returnValue) { return returnValue; }
      break;
    case 'function':
      return returnValue;
  }
  // Return the constructed instance.
  return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for very quick answers! I've only had the chance to try Mike Samuel's function yet. When I do d = applyCtor(Date, [2000, ...]), I get an object that claims to be a Date, and it has e.g. a getYear function, but when I try d.getYear(), Firefox says "Date.prototype.getYear called on incompatible Object". In Safari I just get a "Type error".

Comment: I have now tried both of T.J. Crowder's applyConstruct functions, but when I do my Date tests, I get exactly the same results as with Mike's function (see my previous comment, above). :-(

Comment: I think I fixed this with the triangle of hackery in some older code that I can't find anymore.  The basic idea was
  `switch (args.length) { case 0: return new ctor; case 1: return new ctor(args[0]); case 2: return new ctor(args[0], args[1]); ... }`
up to 12 with a default as above, which handles all host objects with constructors that I know of.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: A small correction: `Date` and other such objects are *built-in objects*. *Host objects* are those which are implementation-defined, such as DOM objects.

Comment: @Casablanca: Where I said "intrinsic" in the code above, I meant to include built-in objects.  Intrinsics include built-in objects and other constructs specified completely by the language definition like primitive value types.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Thanks a lot! Your triangle-of-hackery version seems to work well. I just had to replace a few semicolons with colons (case 1; through case 12;) ... ;-) I'm not sure what you mean by "Warning: The goggles! They do nothing!". Could you explain?

Comment: @Mike Samuel: If I understand your triangle-of-hackery version, the code below the triangle switch is just for cases when args.length > 12. Is that right?

Comment: One subject that hasn't been touched yet, is "what's the best way to produce the constructor from the name of the constructor?". I see two ways: eval(ctorName), and window[ctorName]. Any comments?

Comment: @JonK  Yes, the triangle of hackery is only for the > 12 case.  For "The goggles, they do nothing" see http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site:thedailywtf.com+%22the+goggles%22

Comment: It seems odd to me that this is the only way to handle what I think should be a built-in language feature!

Comment: @ErikE, Yeah.  It's a hole in the language's reflection.  See my edits for a way to do this in ES 5.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I ended up using a variation on [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3871769/57611).

Answer (score 1):

I may end up with this simplified version of Mike's triangle-of-hackery:

```
function applyCtor2(ctor, args) {
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0: return new ctor();
    case 1: return new ctor(args[0]);
    case 2: return new ctor(args[0], args[1]);
    // add more cases if you like
  }
  var jsStr = "new ctor(args[0]";
  for (var i=1; i<ar.length; i++) jsStr += ",args[" + i + "]";
  jsStr += ")";
  return eval(jsStr);
}
```

I'm not using 'apply' here, but I don't miss it. ;-) Any comments?