# Apply an array to a Constructor function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, apply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible)
>   [How to construct JavaScript object (using 'apply')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226646/how-to-construct-javascript-object-using-apply)

Let's say I have a function like this one:

```
var Foo = function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
...
}
```

I understand it is equivalent to call it in these two ways:

```
Foo(a, b, c, d)
Foo.apply(this, [a, b, c, d])
```

Let's say now I use the function to create an object:

```
var myObject = new Foo(a, b, c, d);
```

If I already have the arguments in an array [a, b, c, d], how can I call the function with the new operator an also pass the parameters with the array, like I did with apply above?

Consider I cannot modify the definition of Foo, and I don't wan't to explicitly extract the parameters a, b, c, d from [a, b, c, d]

Thanks!

Comment: The duplicates are not 'exact' (they're overcomplicated whereas your question is simple), basically, you just need to use your new object instead of 'this' when you call apply: `var myObject = {}; Foo.apply(myObject, [a, b, c, d])`

Comment: What is wrong with the 'Foo.apply(this, [a, b, c, d])'. I just ran into this issue and simply dropped the 'new' in favor of doing something like: var myfoo = Foo.apply(this, [a, b, c, d])