# Strange Javascript 'new' form

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I found next form of new operator in the less documentation.

```
var parser = new (less.Parser) ({
    pathes [
        '.',
        './css'
    ],
    filename: 'style.less'
});
```

What the differences from the usual form?

```
var parser = new less.Parser({
    patches [
        '.',
        './css'
    ],
    filename: 'style.less'
});
```

Can it be combined with .apply method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference between

```
var parser = new (less.Parser) (...);
```

and

```
var parser = new less.Parser (...);
```

The parens around `less.Parser` are entirely superfluous.

> Can it be combined with .apply method?

It's difficult to use a function designed to be called via `new` (a "constructor function") via `apply`, because `new` does a lot of things. (This is true of both forms of the above, since — again — they're the same thing.) I talk about using `apply` with constructor functions more [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871769/157247) here on Stack Overflow.