# Javascript inheritance – create instance of same type

Tags: javascript, oop

say I have a class `BaseClass` and two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` which inherit from `BaseClass` via

```
ClassA.prototype = Object.create( BaseClass.prototype );
```

I want to write a method that, if called from an instance of `ClassA`, returns a new instance of `ClassA` and if called from an instance of `ClassB`, returns a new instance of `ClassB` – and I'm wondering what the best way is to do so.
Currently, after fiddling around, I came up with the following solution, which seems to work just fine:

```
// this is added additionally to the above mentioned inheritance setup
ClassA.prototype.constructor = ClassA;
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;

BaseClass.prototype.newInstance = function () {
    var constructor = this.constructor,
        ClassFactory = constructor.bind.apply( constructor, [constructor].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ) );

    return new ClassFactory();
};
```

The obvious downside is to overwrite the prototype's constructor, which feels wrong, because the prototype's constructor in fact *was* `BaseClass`.

Another way that should work is the approach of overriding:

```
BaseClass.prototype.newInstance = function () {
    throw new Error( 'Cannot call abstract method.' );
};

/** @override */
ClassA.prototype.newInstance = function () {
    var ClassFactory = ClassA.bind.apply( ClassA, [ClassA].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ) );

    return new ClassFactory();
};

// ... do the same for ClassB
```

Now my question would be asking for some insight on which strategy is better and why, what are up- and downsides to each and maybe even if there is a better way?

*Edit*: To clarify what the goal is, I want to end up doing something like this:

```
BaseClass.prototype.someMethod = function () {
    var instance = this.getInstance();
    instance.someMethod();

    return instance;
};
```

Now, since `ClassA` and `ClassB` will inherit this method, I want it to return a new instance of the same class that it was called from.

Comment: Just from the question title, I would suggest taking a look at Typescript. http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware that there are many libraries, frameworks and other things out there, some of which I know, some of them I don't know. My class structure is actually not too complicated (interface -> base class -> three subclasses), so I want to stick with plain Javascript for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ClassA.prototype.constructor = ClassA;
> ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;
> ```
>
> The obvious downside is to overwrite the prototype's constructor, which feels wrong, because the prototype's constructor in fact was BaseClass.

No, the prototype objects were not constructed by `BaseClass`. You just `Object.create`d them, and even `BaseClass.prototype` was created as a plain `Object`.

Setting the `constructor` property on an object [back] to the function which constructs instances inheriting from that object is just what the property was made for, and is correct in this case. I don't see what would be wrong with this very simple, practical, efficient and expected solution…

Especially if that `getInstance` factory does more things than just instantiation, and those are the same for all subclasses, the "override solution" looses DRYness.

However, maybe you don't need that extra method at all and should just use `new this.constructor(args…)` everywhere.

> ```
> var ClassFactory = constructor.bind.apply( constructor, [constructor].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ) );
> return new ClassFactory();
> ```

looks a bit complicated, especially I'm not sure whether this works with all `bind` shims. Have a look at [dynamic object construction in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3871731/1048572) or [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1606797/1048572).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually didn't think of using `new this.constructor(...);` before (d'oh!), but I don't like it completely. It will work, but only if I don't wrap it in a function (like `newInstance`). However, I don't want to lose flexibility by "inlining" it everywhere. Plus, I need a second method that will do the same as `newInstance` for two subclasses, but for a third subclass use one of the other subclasses. Since I like to think more modern rather than forcing myself to support outdated browsers, I think I'll stick with my solution (given there are no other concerns). Thanks!

Comment: (I'll wait some more time for potential other answers before marking an answer as the correct one)