# 'new' vs. 'apply' when creating objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6

Background: I am working in Knockout and have implemented a [custom component loader](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html). Specifically, I am implementing the `loadComponent` and `createViewModel` methods for dependency injection purposes. So basically, I determine the appropriate constructor by some convention and then call `new` on it with the required dependencies.

My question: when I have this..

```
function model(arg1, arg2) {
    this.foo = arg1;
    this.bar = arg2;
}
```

What exactly is the difference between:

```
var instance = new model(arg1, arg2);
```

and:

```
var instance = {};
model.apply(instance, [arg1, arg2]);
```

Both seem to have the same result. As for my specific use case, I want to do something like:

```
var instance = {};
model.apply(new Proxy(instance, handler), [arg1, arg2]);
```

Where `handler` would translate something like:

```
this.foo = 'bar';
```

into:

```
this.foo = ko.observable('bar');
```

..to abstract the clunky observable syntax of Knockout.

1. Is this a terrible idea?
2. Is there a better / easier way?
3. What the implications of doing this instead of `new`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not the differences affect your use case or not, but there is definitely some additional stuff that happens when you call `new model` that doesn't happen with `model.apply`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3871769/560114.

Comment: If you depend on `model.apply({} ...)` and you get weird behaviour at some point, I wouldn't be surprised in the slightest. Generally, I would recommend avoiding clever code. MattBrowne's link has great information about behaviours of `new` that you need to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and links. Sounds like if I don't care about the prototype chain (I don't in this case), I don't have anything to worry about.