# Trying to initiate a constructor by string in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example I have a class called Daah, I'd like to instantiate it using a dynamic string variable:

```
class Daah{

}

var classname = "Daah";
var obj = new window[classname];
```

I thought this would work but returns undefined. Is there a way to dynamically create constructors?

Comment: You might get a fair idea about the dynamic object construction from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871769/7994074

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the class to the window:

```
class Daah{

}

window.Daah = Daah;
var classname = "Daah";
var obj = new window[classname]; // class Daah {  }
```